# Carousel with items per page

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, carousel, jcarousel, owl-carousel

Anyone knows a carousel plugin that I can set the number of items per page, like the image below?

PLUS: It has to be responsive.

I tried [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/), but I can't define it properly. I can define the number of items, but only horizontally.
There is [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/), but I'm not sure it is possible with responsive width's.

Anyone have - any - light? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you need the number of items to change dynamically? most of those will work if you use a container element as the slide.

Comment: But I have to use SQL, so I will have to split it on the programming... not really cool

Comment: Maybe an idea to split items per container, dinamically?